# Diseño de clases en Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, poo, class, diseño-de-clases

Estoy diseñando una clase, que permita que los métodos de una pantalla sean más legibles al no tener una cantidad excesiva de código, además de hacer mas amigable el uso de DevExpress a alguien sin experiencia en el mismo.

Dichos métodos lo que hacen, es obtener el valor de columnas dentro de un grid, ya sea recorriendo todo el grid o solo los rows seleccionados y asignandole dicho valor a un TextBox o ComboBox.

Actualmente la clase les soluciona el problema de no saber obtener los valores de un grid en devexpress, ya que es más amigable el uso de la clase. El problema que no logro solucionar es la cantidad de código repetido.

Por ejemplo en un método que asigna valores a los TextBox, se ve de la siguiente manera:

```
Private Sub grdConsulta_DoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles grdConsulta.DoubleClick
        Try
            If grdDatos.SelectedRowsCount > 0 Then
                txtDosis1.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis1).ToString
                txtDosis2.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis2).ToString
                txtDosis3.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis3).ToString
                txtDosis4.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis4).ToString
                txtDosis5.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis5).ToString
                txtDosis6.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis6).ToString
                txtDosis7.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis7).ToString
                txtDosis8.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis8).ToString
                txtDosis9.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis9).ToString
                txtDosis10.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis10).ToString
                txtDosis11.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis11).ToString
                txtDosis12.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis12).ToString
                txtDosis13.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis13).ToString
                txtDosis14.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis14).ToString
                txtDosis15.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis15).ToString
                txtDosis16.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis16).ToString
                txtDosis17.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis17).ToString
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error en grdConsulta" & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Mensaje del Sistema")
        End Try
End Sub
```

Y con la clase nueva, si bien es más amigable al uso, la cantidad del código es prácticamente la misma:

```
 Private Sub grdConsulta_DoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles grdConsulta.DoubleClick
        Try
            If grdDatos.SelectedRowsCount > 0 Then
                Dim val As New ClsColumnasDX
                txtValor1.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades1, 0, True)
                txtValor2.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades2, 0, True)
                txtValor3.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades3, 0, True)
                txtValor4.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades4, 0, True)
                txtValor5.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades5, 0, True)
                txtValor6.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades6, 0, True)
                txtValor7.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades7, 0, True)
                txtValor8.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades8, 0, True)
                txtValor9.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades9, 0, True)
                txtValor10.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades10, 0, True)
                txtValor11.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades11, 0, True)
                txtValor12.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades12, 0, True)
                txtValor13.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades13, 0, True)
                txtValor14.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades14, 0, True)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error en grdConsulta" & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Mensaje del Sistema")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

La clase que se diseñó es la siguiente(aún en construcción):

```
Public Class ClsColumnasDX
    Public _Val As String
    Public Property Val() As String
        Get
            Return _Val
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Val = value
        End Set
    End Property
    'Recorre el grid solo en los rows seleccionados
    Public Function ValRowsSelected(ByVal Grid As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView, ByVal Column As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn, ByVal Row As String, Optional ByVal getCodigo As Boolean = False) As String
        Try
            Val = Grid.GetRowCellValue(Grid.GetSelectedRows(Row), Column).ToString()
            If getCodigo Then Val = Get_Codigo(Val)
            Return Val
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
    'Recorre todo el grid
    Public Function ValRows(ByVal Grid As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView, ByVal Column As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn, ByVal Row As String, Optional ByVal getCodigo As Boolean = False) As String
        Try
            Val = Grid.GetRowCellValue(Row, Column).ToString()
            If getCodigo Then Val = Get_Codigo(Val)
            Return Val
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Y para obtener el valor a un TextBox:

```
txtValor.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades, 0, True)
```

Alguien puede ayudarme, con sugerencias de como programar la clase, para evitar esas grandes cantidades de código?

Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

Comment: ¡Buenos días @raintrooper! ¿Por qué ejecutas la misma instrucción **N** cantidad de veces? por ejemplo: 

`txtDosis.Text = grdDatos.GetRowCellValue(grdDatos.GetSelectedRows(0), Dosis).ToString`

Con una vez que ejecutes dicha línea, es más que suficiente. O es que ¿Cada línea cambia de valores? por ejemplo:

`txtValor0.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades, 0, True)`
`txtValor1.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades, 1, True)`
.
.
.
`txtValorN.Text = val.ValRowsSelected(grdDatos, ValorUnidades, N, True)`

Comment: Buenos días, @Ricardo. Solo lo coloqué así como ejemplo, ya en la práctica cambian los nombres de las columnas y los TextBox. Saludos.

Comment: Aún no logro acomodar de muy buena forma el código (vengo empezando a usar esta herramienta). Pero coloqué una idea, pueda que se te sea de utilidad. Si no, avisame y veo como mejoro la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: La clase no esta mal. y es lo que pasa cuando tenes muchas campos a llenar en la pantalla. Si usaras wpf esto se resolveria solo porque la pantalla se bindea automaticamente a una clase y trae los valores que necesita (hace los get y los set automaticamente). O sea, tu codigo no esta mal, es verborragico y correcto.

Comment: Yo te recomendaria usar listas. Una `List<TextBox>` para almacenar los Textboxes, y una `List<string>` para almacenar los valores. De esa manera,con un simple bucle `for` podrías rellenar todos los datos.

Comment: Yo miraría usar el databinding de los textbox para evitar código de ese tipo.